# Spring Yml configuration for CORS not used

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot

I have configured the allowed origins for CORS in the Spring yml configuration as follows.

```
endpoints:
  cors:
    allowed-origins: http://client.local
    allow-credentials: true
```

But it wasn't applied until I added a Java configuration as follows

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value("${endpoints.cors.allowed-origins}")
    private String allowedOrigins;
    @Value("${endpoints.cors.allow-credentials}")
    private boolean allowCredentials;

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/api/**")
                .allowedOrigins(allowedOrigins)
                .allowCredentials(allowCredentials);
    }
}
```

I want to keep the yml configuration and discard the Java configuration, why is the yml config not applied?

Answer (score 0):

I know, it might be too late, but I'll try...
Have you added `spring-boot-starter-actuator` to your dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using custom properties use endpoints provided by Spring Boot.

Ex:

```
management.endpoints.web.cors.allowed-origins=http://domain:port
```

[Spring Boot Application.properties configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html)